# .Net Runtime instantiating from multiple but identical assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I'm currently struggling with instantiating one class from multiple but identical assemblies during runtime. Here's my setup:

- I've got a native executable that is able to load multiple DLLs at runtime. Since my "target DLLs" are .Net assemblies, I do the following (for each target DLL!):
  Load a C++/CLI DLL (aka `DynamicLoader`) to get a bridge between native and .Net world. After that an instance of the actual class from the target DLL will be created.
- To be able to unload the target .Net DLL during runtime I've implemented a plugin-like system based on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8832/Plug-in-Manager.
  Short summary of it: The DynamicLoader has two classes `LocalLoader` and `RemoteLoader`. An instance of `LocalLoader` is created in the "root" AppDomain (which is created when the first C++/CLI DLL is loaded). This `LocalLoader` then creates a new "target AppDomain" and instantiates the `RemoteLoader` into it. This `RemoteLoader` will then load the target assembly and instanciates the target class.
- So I've got 2+ AppDomains. One AppDomain that will be auto-created by the native executable loading the first C++/CLI DLL and one AppDomain per "target AppDomain".
- Each target DLL will have its own copy of the `DynamicLoader` assembly and each target DLL will reside in its own directory.

My current problem lies at the point when the `RemoteLoader` is instantiated. First, some source to show you what I'm doing (without the catch-lines) :

```cpp
void LocalLoader::InitializeRemoteLoader()
{
    // Load the RemoteLoader assembly (which is actually the current one)
    Assembly^ remoteLoaderAssembly = Assembly::GetAssembly(DynamicLoader::RemoteLoader::typeid);
    String^ remoteLoaderCodeBase = remoteLoaderAssembly->CodeBase;

    // Create new AppDomainSetup with appropriate name and base directory.
    AppDomainSetup^ appDomainSetup = gcnew AppDomainSetup();
    appDomainSetup->ApplicationName = m_targetAssemblyName + "_AppDomain";
    appDomainSetup->ApplicationBase = Path::GetDirectoryName(remoteLoaderAssembly->Location);
    appDomainSetup->PrivateBinPath = String::Empty;

    // Create AppDomain for RemoteLoader and target DLL
    try
    {
        m_targetAppDomain = AppDomain::CreateDomain(appDomainSetup->ApplicationName, nullptr, appDomainSetup);
    }
    catch (Exception^ e1)
    {
        // ERROR!
    }

    // Finally, create a new instance of the RemoteLoader and store the instance locally.
    if (m_targetAppDomain != nullptr)
    {
        try
        {
            Object^ newInstance = m_targetAppDomain->CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
                remoteLoaderCodeBase,
                "DynamicLoader.RemoteLoader");

            if (newInstance != nullptr)
            {
                m_remoteLoader = (DynamicLoader::RemoteLoader^)(newInstance);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception^ e1)
        {
            // ERROR!
            Log4NetProvider::LocalLogger->Fatal("Could not type cast new instance of RemoteLoader to appropriate type!");
            Log4NetProvider::LocalLogger->FatalFormat("Created instance of type \"{0}\" from \"{1}\".", newInstance->GetType(), newInstance->GetType()->Assembly->CodeBase);
            Log4NetProvider::LocalLogger->FatalFormat("Tried to cast to type \"{0}\" from \"{1}\".", RemoteLoader::typeid, RemoteLoader::typeid->Assembly->CodeBase);

            Log4NetProvider::LocalLogger->FatalFormat(".NET Exception message: {0}", typeConvException->ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs at the "last line" `m_remoteLoader = (DynamicLoader::RemoteLoader^)(newInstance);`. For the first time the `DynamicLoader` is doing its work, everything is ok. The second time, the type casting fails with

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'DynamicLoader.RemoteLoader'.

I tried to analyse which assemblies are actually used at what point and discovered that:

- `remoteLoaderCodeBase` is always pointing to the correct assembly-file, so the assembly of each "target DLL" in its own directory.
- `newInstance->GetType()->Assembly->CodeBase` points to the first `DynamicLoader` assembly.
- `RemoteLoader::typeid->Assembly->CodeBase` points to the current `DynamicLoader` assembly.

So, long story short: even though I explicitly tell `m_targetAppDomain->CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(...)` to instantiate my class from a specific assembly, it will create the instance from the first assembly loaded in the root AppDomain! What am I doing wrong? I guess this should work somehow, but I don't see the solution...

Ah, one last point: I'm working with .Net 4.0, so if there are any better ways to do it, tell me. ;)

Comment: Having more than one DynamicLoader type is the usual problem with casts failing like this.  Type identity in .NET doesn't just include the namespace name and type name, it also includes the assembly it came from.  A hard requirement therefore is to have only *one* assembly with the DynamicLoader type.  It needs to be referenced by both projects.  Do avoid trying to re-invent your own plug-in framework, that has been done.

Comment: Sure, I always try to avoid reinventing the wheel. The only reason I'm doing all this is to be able to unload the "target DLL" so I can update it without exiting the native application (which has no ability to unload DLLs, even native ones). I am open for suggestions if there is a better way to achieve that requirement!